# How iterate through tuple and range

Tags: python, tuples, range

Am trying to iterate through tuple and range so that i will add the range `numbers` to tuple when it is printed.

```
for mt in range(1, 8):
    print(mt)

my_tuple = (("ben", "monday"),("john", "tuesday"),("steve", "wednesday"),("Isaac","thursday"),("van", "friday"),("tom", "saturday"),("bryan","sunday"))

for row in my_tuple:
    print(row)
```

This is the result expected

```
(1, 'ben', 'monday')
(2, 'john', 'tuesday')
(3, 'steve', 'wednesday')
(4, 'Isaac', 'thursday')
(5, 'van', 'friday')
(6, 'tom', 'saturday')
(7, 'bryan', 'sunday')
```

Comment: You cannot change the tuple. It is already indexed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index of the row:

```py
list_of_tuples = [("ben", "monday"),("john", "tuesday"),("steve", "wednesday"),("Isaac","thursday"),("van", "friday"),("tom", "saturday"),("bryan","sunday")]

for i, row in enumerate(list_of_tuples, 1):
    print((i, *row))
```

Comment: Perhaps to clarify to beginners: the second argument `1` is the index where to start from. By default the index starts at 0 but you can change it to the number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

By using list comprehension:

```
my_tuple = (("ben", "monday"),("john", "tuesday"),("steve", "wednesday"),("Isaac","thursday"),("van", "friday"),("tom", "saturday"),("bryan","sunday"))

print([(i+1, t[0], t[1]) for i, t in enumerate(my_tuple)])

# [(1, 'ben', 'monday'), (2, 'john', 'tuesday'), (3, 'steve', 'wednesday'), (4, 'Isaac', 'thursday'), (5, 'van', 'friday'), (6, 'tom', 'saturday'), (7, 'bryan', 'sunday')]
```

UPDATE: Or even better as mentioned in comments:

```
[(i, *t) for i, t in enumerate(my_tuple, 1)]
```

Comment: Using `enumerate(my_tuple, 1)` would be more efficient than doing `i+1` for each individual item.

Comment: Yes, it's true.